# How to hide url on mouse hover of a hyper link

Tags: javascript

I'm my backend part of the app which is built in PHP Symfony I have HTML twig files, I want to change behavior for some href link, I want to hide URL in the bottom left corner after I hover them, I tried this solution that needs to change URL text to Contact, but it won't work

```html
<a 
  class="activo" 
  href="link" 
  onmouseover="window.status='Contact'"
  onmouseout="window.status=''"
>
  Click
</a>
```

any help?

Comment: Showing the link URL is a browser behavior. It's like saying you want ads to be shown, but your client uses an ad blocker. You have to save the URL somewhere either in a variable or some attribute of an element, either way your client (the visitor) can (with some web knowledge) figure out those URLs anyway. Maybe if you could explain why you need to hide the URL maybe we could offer you a solution for that initial problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR;** Simply use `JavaScript`, like:

```
window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";
```

---

Remove the "`<a ...>`" element's `href`-attribute.

Then make it trigger a JavaScript function:

```
<a onclick="myFunction()">my link</a>
```

Finally, simply use `JavaScript` to redirect, like:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction() {
    window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";
  }
</script>
```

> **Note** that you may need to add `CSS` to set cursor, I mean, already existing `CSS` may check `href`'s existence, and not apply once `href` is removed.

### Reusing same function

```html
<a data-url="https://stackoverflow.com"
   onclick="myFunction(this)">my link label</a>

<!-- In case you are using Twig or Blade: -->
<a data-url="{{ 'https://example.com' }}"
   onclick="myFunction(this)">my other link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(element) {
    window.location.href = element.getAttribute('data-url');
  }
</script>
```